# How to disable translations during unit tests in django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm using [Django Internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/) tools to translate some strings from my application. The code looks like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
def my_view(request):
    output = _("Welcome to my site.")
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Then, I'm writing unit tests using the [Django test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client). These tests make a request to the view and compare the returned contents.

How can I disable the translations while running the unit tests? I'm aiming to do this:

```
class FoobarTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Do something here to disable the string translation. But what?
        # I've already tried this, but it didn't work:
        django.utils.translation.deactivate_all()
    def testFoobar(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.get("/foobar")
        # I want to compare to the original string without translations.
        self.assertEquals(response.content.strip(), "Welcome to my site.")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this same issue with approach number 4. from @Denilson Sá's answer. It turns out this does not require any test-specific settings file and can be defined on a per-test basis with a decorator or context manager provided by django (see [overriding settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings)).

It can be used like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

class MyTest(TestCase):
    @override_settings(LANGUAGE_CODE='en-US', LANGUAGES=(('en', 'English'),))
    def test_mypage(self):
        // ...
```

The decorator can also be applied to the entire TestCase subclass, or for even more fine-grained control there is also a context manager (see the docs linked above).

Being this rather common for me, I also defined:

```
english = override_settings(
    LANGUAGE_CODE='en-US',
    LANGUAGES=(('en', 'English'),),
)
```

So that now I can simply use `@english` on the test cases requiring it.

Answer (score 14):

Calling `.get()` or `.post()` on the test client will run all the configured middlewares. This means it will also run `LocaleMiddleware`, which will call `translation.get_language_from_request()` followed by `translation.activate(language)`.

What this means is that the currently active language is ignored and thrown away when writing tests using the test client. In other words, the following code does not work:

```
def testFoobar(self):
    c = Client()
    # This will not work.
    translation.deactivate_all()
    # This will not work either.
    translation.activate('en-us')
    # The next call will override the earlier activate/deactivate calls.
    response = c.get("/foobar")
```

There a few solutions:

1. Setting the desired language at the session object.
2. Setting the desired language at a cookie.
3. Sending `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header.
4. Setting `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`

Source (from Django 1.4, but it is mostly unchanged since 1.1 or earlier):

- [`django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L366)
- [`django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware.process_request()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/middleware/locale.py#L20)

Answer (score 1):

I would think it would make more sense to just force the language to a known setting for your unit tests. This means you're testing something which is closer to the real implementation.

To activate a specific language you could do this in your setup:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate
...
activate('en-en')
```

Comment: It might be a good idea, do you have suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: FYI, your answer does not work, for the reasons I've explained in my own answer. Nice try, though, but it simply does not work.

Comment: Thanks, helped me to test my views, i've just set up localization to 'en' and it went smooth :)